# Uninstall Code Recommenders Plugin in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I cannot get Code Recommenders uninstalled. After I removed it via the Marketplace, this popped up next time I started it. Installing it will re-install the Code Recommenders feature, which I do not want. I can "Skip" it, but then it will just ask again on the next start.

---

**Requirements Update**

The installation does not satisfy the requirements listed below.

- org.eclipse.recommenders.mylyn.rcp.feature
- org.eclipse.recommenders.news.rcp.feature
- org.eclipse.recommenders.rcp.feature
- org.eclipse.recommenders.snipmatch.rcp.feature

---

[image]

---

Where can I look and what do I need to look for to find out what is requiring these features to be installed, so I can remove it as well?

Comment: Try the 'remember my decision' check box with Skip

Comment: @greg-449 But that seems to only suppress the problem. I want to know why Eclipse thinks this requirement is needed in the first place, after I explicitly uninstalled Code Recommenders.